# Lenovo IdeaPad C340

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lenovo, touchscreen

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as a dual boot (with Windows 10) on my newly aquired Lenovo IdeaPad C340, and I have two problems.
The first one is that when I start it (or restart it) it sometimes just freeze on a black screen and I can't do anything but switch it off manually (by presing the start button). I think it comes from ubuntu, but I did not use my Windows 10 boot many times, so I can't tell if it actually happens with windows 10 too (it yet).
Second problem, still at start, it happens that the cursor of my mouse does not appear. I can still use the touchscreen but any click on something else than the hub where are located the power off button etc. does not work. I found that I could stop the problem by closing the session and opening it again, but I don't know how to stop it once for all.
Does anybody have a solution? Or at least a suggestion?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think it does yes! The thing is I have to wait to see if the problem happens again. In something like one week I should see if it still happens. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I can say it didn't solve the cursor problem at least (it just happened). But I noticed that the cursor does not appear but still exists. I think it was supposed to only solve the black screen problem